# Parse an RPM name into its components

Tags: rpm

Is there a name-parsing tool that is part of the official RPM tool package?

I have a list of filenames. Each is the filename of an RPM package. I don't have the actual packages, just the filenames.  For each I need to extract the package name and version ($NAME and $VERSION).  The reason I need this is I am writing a script that then makes sure that "yum install $VERSION" installs $VERSION.  This is part of a system that builds packages and verifies they are properly uploaded.

The list of filenames looks like:

```
$ cat /tmp/packages.txt
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/emacs-mercurial-2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/emacs-mercurial-el-2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/mercurial-2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/mercurial-hgk-2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/python-redis-2.8.0-2.el6.noarch.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/redis-2.6.16-1.el6.1.x86_64.rpm
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/sei_dnsmaster-1.0-99.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I found [the following code](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4386/parse-an-rpm-name-into-its-components-fast) which is a BASH function that does the task:

```
function parse_rpm() { RPM=$1;B=${RPM##*/};B=${B%.rpm};A=${B##*.};B=${B%.*};R=${B##*-};B=${B%-*};V=${B##*-};B=${B%-*};N=$B;echo "$N $V $R $A"; }

for i in $(</tmp/packages.txt) ; do
    parse_rpm $i
done
```

It works.  Mostly.  There are some exceptions:

```
$ parse_rpm CentOS/6/x86_64/sei_dnsmaster-1.0-99.el6.x86_64.rpm
sei_dnsmaster 1.0 99.el6 x86_64
```

Notice that it didn't get the version correctly (it should be 1.0-99)

I'm wondering (1) if there is a tool in the rpmdev package that does this correctly.  (2) If not, is there an official regex I could use.  (3) What is the python equivalent of that regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify where you are getting your input from and the format it takes please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've been told the official way to do what I'm seeking is in Python:

```
from rpmUtils.miscutils import splitFilename

(n, v, r, e, a) = splitFilename(filename)
```

I've written a short Python program that does what I need.  I will offer the script to the rpmdev project for inclusion.

Comment: The Debian package naming rules are so simple and straghtforward - I do not know how the rpm world has ended up in such a mess.

Please could you paste your script into the answer here?

Comment: @PaulHedderly You can take a look at the [source code for `splitFilename`](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/4ed25525ee4781907bd204018c27f44948ed83fe/rpmUtils/miscutils.py#L301-L329). It's pretty much just delimiters parsed from right to left, with the rest being the package name.

Answer (score 29):

You don't need to do any of this; RPM has a query format argument which will let you specify exactly the data you want to receive. It will even output without line endings if you don't specify them.

For instance:

```
rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}" -q coreutils
rpm --queryformat "The version of %{NAME} is %{VERSION}\n" -q coreutils

rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}" -qp file.rpm
```

The complete list of variables you can use can be obtained with:

```
rpm --querytags
```

Note that in the case of `RELEASE`, output like `84.el6` is normal and expected, since this is actually how RPM packages are versioned when packaged by or for a distribution.

Comment: That only works with installed packages.  I want to manipulate filenames.  `$ rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}" -q CentOS/6/x86_64/sei_dnsmaster-1.0-84.el6.x86_64.rpm
package CentOS/6/x86_64/sei_dnsmaster-1.0-84.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed`

Comment: @TomOnTime Wait a minute... So you don't care what's actually in the package?

Comment: Correct.  I have a file name and I want to accurately extract the package name and version as two seperate pieces of data.   I'm processing a list of file names... The actual RPMs aren't even on this machine.

Comment: I wish I'd known that sooner. RPM tools only deal with the package contents; the filename is completely irrelevant (and this answer won't work for you).

Comment: Have fun parsing, for instance: `libopenssl0_9_8-32bit-0.9.8j-0.26.1_0.50.1.x86_64.delta.rpm`

Comment: @TomOnTime - "That only works with installed packages"

Not true - you missed the -p option in the third example:

 rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}" -qp file.rpm

Answer (score 4):

I worked out regular expressions that fit all the data I was able to test them with.  I had to use a mixture of greedy and non-greedy matches.  That said, here is my perl and python versions:

Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

foreach (@ARGV) {
    ($path, $name, $version, $release, $platform,
      @junk) = m#(.*/)*(.*)-(.*)-(.*?)\.(.*)(\.rpm)#;
    $verrel = $version . '-' . $release;

    print join("\t", $path, $name, $verrel, $version, $rev, $platform), "\n";
}
```

Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

for x in sys.argv[1:]:
    m = re.search(r'(.*/)*(.*)-(.*)-(.*?)\.(.*)(\.rpm)', x)
    if m:
        (path, name, version, release, platform, _) = m.groups()
        path = path or ''
        verrel = version + '-' + release
        print "\t".join([path, name, verrel, version, release, platform])
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid name: %s\n' % x)
        sys.exit(1)
```

I'd rather have a regex that comes from the RPM project. The one that I invented above will have to do do for now.

Comment: This is mostly similar than my solution (but avoid `.*` unless you REALLY want to match anything). Nice to see that you found by yourself, though !

Comment: The filename strikes me as a bad way to get this information. It may work for a specific set of vendor-provided RPMs (so you may be OK as long as your vendor standardizes third-party stuff and never changes their naming format), but I've seen plenty of creatively-named RPM files. The Acrobat Reader I grabbed from Adobe a few seconds ago is `AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.rpm`) which breaks your regex parsing above.

Comment: True. But Adbe wouldn't work for any solution because it breaks the yum filename standard.  (Technically the question should be about yum filenames, not RPM filenames).

Answer (score 2):

Rpm files can have some funky file names in extreme cases, but generally you can split the NVR on the hyphens. The catch is the N (name) portion of the NVR may contain hyphens and underscores, but the V(version) and R(release) are guaranteed to not have any extraneous hyphens. So you can start by trimming off the VR portion to derive a Name.

```
$ RPM=/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/emacs-mercurial-2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
$ echo ${RPM%-*-*}
/home/builder/packages/testing-dev/CentOS/6/x86_64/emacs-mercurial
```

Building on that you can isolate the Version and Release portion.

```
echo ${RPM#${RPM%-*-*}-*}
2.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Just split the hyphen again to isolate the part you need. And obviously clean out the arch and rpm file extension strings, which is a given. Just giving you an idea of how it could be approached in bash.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the simplest shell way is:

```
ls | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d- -f3- | rev
```

That is: reverse each line, using slash cut just the first part (*emanelif*), then using hyphen cut all but the first two parts (i.e. leave behind *ESAELER* including *emanelif eth fo tser* and *NOISREV*) and reverse the *enil* back.

With your example file:

```
$ cat /tmp/packages.txt | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d- -f3- | rev
emacs-mercurial
emacs-mercurial-el
mercurial
mercurial-hgk
python-redis
redis
sei_dnsmaster
$
```

To get other parts is excercise on reading *cut(1)*.

Comment: Best and most easiest answer so far.  Sometime people tend to over engineer which we must avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -q --queryformat options from rpm as said before, if you want to do this on a non installed package you can specify the rpm with the `-p` option, like this:

```
rpm -q -p ./Downloads/polysh-0.4-1.noarch.rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n"
polysh 0.4 1 noarch
```

e.g.

```
$ ls ./Downloads/*.rpm
./Downloads/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
./Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.6.0-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm
./Downloads/playonlinux-yum-4-1.noarch.rpm
./Downloads/skype-4.2.0.11-fedora.i586.rpm
./Downloads/dbview-1.0.4-2.1.x86_64.rpm
./Downloads/openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm
./Downloads/polysh-0.4-1.noarch.rpm
```

gives me

```
adobe-release-x86_64 1.0 1 noarch
dbview 1.0.4 2.1 x86_64
nautilus-dropbox 1.6.0 1.fc10 x86_64
openmotif22-libs 2.2.4 192.1.3 x86_64
playonlinux-yum 4 1 noarch
polysh 0.4 1 noarch
skype 4.2.0.11 fc16 i586
```

**so just splitting the filename is wrong!**

```
for filename in """<paste list here>""".split():
    print splitFilename(filename)

('./Downloads/adobe-release-x86_64', '1.0', '1', '', 'noarch')
('./Downloads/nautilus-dropbox', '1.6.0', '1.fedora', '', 'x86_64')
('./Downloads/playonlinux-yum', '4', '1', '', 'noarch')
('./Downloads/skype', '4.2.0.11', 'fedora', '', 'i586')
('./Downloads/dbview', '1.0.4', '2.1', '', 'x86_64')
('./Downloads/openmotif22-libs', '2.2.4', '192.1.3', '', 'x86_64')
('./Downloads/polysh', '0.4', '1', '', 'noarch')
```

so **pay attention**, this is not the correct details of the rpm, 
e.g. `1.fedora` is actually `1.fc10` in the rpm.

Comment: I see the confusion.  Not only is the RPM not installed, I don't have it on this machine.  I'm processing lists of packages and file names.  This is for something that manages repo inventories; it doesn't have the actual packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Regular Expressions and/or Perl, that's quite easy.

```
 ls | head | perl -p -e 'm#([^\-]+?)-(.*).rpm$#; print "$1 $2\n";$_=""'
```

or the regex alone :

```
m#([^\-]+?)-(.*).rpm$#
```

If you split it that's :

- anything but a Hyphen, at least one character : `[^\-]+` (escaped because hyphen have a special meaning in character groups)
- stop the match after the first hyphen (and not the last) : `[^\-]+?`
- add this to a capture group : `([^\-]+?)`
- Then a hyphen : `([^\-]+?)-`
- then anything else in another capture group (but the trailing `.rpm`) : `([^\-]+?)-(.*).rpm$`  (the dollar means "end of line")
- enclose than in a practical matching format : `m#([^\-]+?)-(.*).rpm$#`

Done ! Just get both parts in the variables `$1`and `$2`

**Comment on the first one-liner :**

I was in a directory with many rpm files, hence the `ls`.

`perl -p` is equivalent to ;

```
perl -e 'while(<STDIN>){ chomp($_);  [YOUR CODE HERE] ; print($_); }'
```

Which explain that I had to put a null-string in `$_` to avoid perl printing back the line after I have extracted and custom-printed it. Note that I could have used substitutions to aoid this little 'hack'.

Comment: This does not work at all on hundreds of RPM names, e.g. `module-init-tools-3.9-21.el6_4.x86_64.rpm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `dnf info`. Here is an example Bash script to get values and to set as a variable:

```
function dnfinfo() {
   dnf info "$(echo "${1}" | sed 's/\.rpm$//g')"
}

function splitname() {
   eval $(
     dnfinfo "${1}" | \
     grep "^Arch\|^Name\|^Release\|^Version" | \
     sort | \
     awk -F": " {'print "\""$2"\""'} | \
     tr "\n" " " | \
     awk {'print "xarch="$1"~xname="$2"~xrel="$3"~xver="$4'} | \
     tr "~" "\n"
   )
}

splitname "tcpdump-4.9.2-5.el8.x86_64.rpm"
echo "${xname} ${xver} ${xrel} ${xarch}"
```

It will give a result even if the package is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way is, to create a regex which will do one thing, work ;-)
Substring Regex w're disc.:

```
s/^(?:\w{1})(?:-?\w+?\S+?-?){1,}?(\d+[\:|\.]\d+\S+)/$1/g
```

That's the substring regex in perl !

Example:

```
echo  bonnie-++sdsdsœ@@œ=gcc-++++_sded-sdsdsd-fcc-gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.0.1.el7_6.2.x86_64|perl  -pe 's/^(?:\w{1})(?:-?\w+?\S+?-?){1,}?(\d+[\:|\.]\d+\S+)/$1/g'
```

Output:
`4.8.5-36.0.1.el7_6.2.x86_64`

So the version is right.
The regex covers 99,9% of RPM packages names in a single line ;-)

Short explanation:
(?:) Non-capturing  group (i don't want this part -> use it for speed. Always)

\w+: Word Characters (including _)

? Optional match

\S+: Non-Space character

{1,} Not-capture-match the whole group 1 or more

Worx for you and for me !

Answer (score 0):

All of "answers" above that attempt to obtain RPM information from the filename are incorrect.   The correct way is to introspect (inside) the rpm file for this information.   People who wrote several yum ansible modules still don't understand this, and we just reported it as a bug to Red Hat, and they are still trying to resolve it.